# Need help in SAS Macros

Tags: sas

Assuming there is a csv file on below location
C:\temp\Input\Filenames.csv

In this csv, column A consist of FilePath as shown below

**FilePath** 
C:\temp\a_1.xls
C:\temp\a_2.xls
C:\temp\a_3.xls

In each of the above file consist of *BalanceNumber* in column C

I want to write a SAS code that would read the csv file - column A, Get every xls file mentioned in that column, read the balance number on those xls files and save all the balance number in one table called *OutputBalance*.

Appreciate if someone help me with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **filevar** option in infile statement to get this done. Read the filenames.csv file into a dataset which would store your filename with/without the path. Then in next dataset loop through and read the column C from the xls files. I wanted to write down the code, but code based on your requirement is already there on the web. So don't think it's a good idea to write it down again. Refer to the following link : **http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/multi_file_read.htm** . This should help you in writing the code.

Comment: Thanks Sushil. I will look into it and let you know if it worked for me.